# Wrong paths when loading React SPA with nested route, but working when load from root

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I have a strange issue with Webpack and React, but it's more about Webpack.

When I load my dev website, e.g. `app.localhost` it is working fine and works even if I will go to `app.localhost/path/further-path`.

However, it is not working if I will enter `app.localhost/path/further-path` when opening the dev server or will refresh with that path.

Anyone had this kind of issue and can help?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

In config:

```js
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    publicPath: '/' // this was missing
  },
```